# Change from jQuery to Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all the jQuery dependency in the `$(document).ready()` function.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $("#canvas1").mousedown(handleMouseDown);
  $(document).keydown(handleKeyDown);
}, false);
```

If handleKeyDown and handleMouseDown are previously declared functions in the same file `function handleMouseDown() and function handleKeyDown()`, how do I replace the jQuery with native javascript?

Comment: refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    document.getElementById('canvas1').onmousedown = handleMouseDown;

    document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;

}, false);
```

Comment: And I guess "$("#canvas1").mousemove(handleMouseMove)" would be "document.getElementById('canvas1').onmousemove = handleMouseMove"?